# What does the sharp (#) sign mean in a vim script function definition?

Tags: vim

So I was looking for ways to get some object oriented stuff in vimcript when I found [this page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/VimL_Script_language#Object_oriented_programming)

So for instance:

```
   function gnat#Make () dict
      ...
      return
   endfunction gnat#Make
```

- What does the '#' mean?
- Does it have to do with ending the function explicitly like that?
  (usually one just `endfu[nction]` without the function name)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` is for autoload scripts. Try `:h autoload` for more info.

I don't think that "explicit" function ending is allowed, as written in the vim help:

```
:endf[unction]   The end of a function definition.  Must be on a line
                 by its own, without other commands.
```

But it appears that when you try to put something after `:endf`, even if it's not the name of the function, no error occurs.